# Angular 7 Get Data From API

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to get data from API using GET method. Actually, I need `"noPage"`, `"totalPage"` , `"List":[]`

**This is the response from API**

```
{
    "status": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "Success."
    },
    "noPage": 5,
    "totalPage": 9,
    "List": [
        {
            "_id": "CFB2D5FFDFDADDB954404BF1B9D59844",
            "createdDate": "2019-06-25T08:42:27.799+0000",
            "createdBy": "Josh",
            "enable": "true",
            "remarks": null,
            "Id": "0044",
            "Name": "Trisya"
]

}
```

Then I'm using this method to get data

**Service**

```
getService(): Observable<any>  {
    const urls: string = `http://192.168.0.101:9080/project/api/listall/${Id}`

    return this.http.get<AgentDetails>(urls).pipe(map(res => res['List']));

  }
```

I only success get data in `"List": []` only not `"noPage"`and `"totalPage"`

How I need to do to get `"noPage"`and `"totalPage"`

Hope you all can help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are taking out only list from the object in the `map` function:

```
map(res => res['List']);
```

the `res['List']` will return only `List`. If you want to return more information, you can use:

```
map(res => {
    return {
      List: res['List'],
      noPage: res['noPage'],
      totalPage: res['totalPage']
    };
}
```

checkout the documentation for `map` for more information

Comment: Thank you dude.. it work.. I got the value... But It come out error `ERROR TypeError: "_this.dataSource.data.map is not a function"`

Comment: The error came on this code ? Or some other place ?

Comment: i've figured out the error. it come from other place. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try below example,

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dljtkv

Service Class

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

import { AgentDetails } from './agent-details';

@Injectable()
export class AgentService {

  constructor( public http: HttpClient,) { }

  getService(): Observable<AgentDetails>  {
     const urls: string = `http://192.168.0.101:9080/project/api/listall/${Id}`

    // const urls = "/assets/agent-details.json";

    return this.http.get<AgentDetails>(urls);

  }

}
```

Component Class

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {AgentService} from './agent.service';
import { AgentDetails } from './agent-details';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent   {
  name = 'Angular';

  agentDetails:AgentDetails;

  constructor(public agentService: AgentService){
      this.getAgentDetails();
  }


  getAgentDetails(){
    this.agentService.getService().subscribe(data=>{
      this.agentDetails = data;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.agentDetails));
    })
  }


}
```

Model classes

```
import { Status } from './status';
import { Agent } from './agent';
export class AgentDetails {
  status: Status;
  noPage:number;
  totalPage:number;
  List: Agent[];

}

export class Status {

  code:number;
  message:string;
}

export class Agent {


  _id: string;
  createdDate: Date;
  createdBy: string;
  enable: boolean;
  remarks: string;
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
}
```

Comment: @swapy please check is this what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
map(res => res['List'])
```

this runs the function

```
res => res['List']
```

on the results, this is stating you want to take the response and return just the property list. So your results are exactly what that map function does.

Get rid of the map to get the entire response.

Comment: Thanks dude for your answer.. But how to get data `"noPage"` and `"totalPage"`?  when i `console.log(this.dataSource)` it only display data from `"List": []`

Comment: Don't pipe anything, just return return this.http.get<AgentDetails>(urls) and you will get the whole response.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to define an Interface for the response you are getting.

For example define one interface like this

```js
interface UserAPIResponse {
  status: Status;
  noPage: number;
  totalPage: number;
  List: UserList[];
}

interface UserList {
  _id: string;
  createdDate: string;
  createdBy: string;
  enable: string;
  remarks?: any;
  Id: string;
  Name: string;
}

interface Status {
  code: number;
  message: string;
}
```

Now you can pick the desired attributes out of your response

```js
getService(): Observable<any>  {
    const urls: string = `http://192.168.0.101:9080/project/api/listall/${Id}`

    return this.http.get<AgentDetails>(urls).pipe(
       map(({noPage, totalPage, List} : UserAPIResponse) => {noPage, totalPage, List));

}
```

Now as a response you will get an Object with only these 3 attributes.

If you want to understand a bit more read about destructuring.